# Why KS test reject null-hypothesis in the comparison of fitted data vs "true" fitted data?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

Imagine you run a linear regression $E[Y \mid X=x] = X^\prime\beta$ and compute the fitted values $X^\prime \hat \beta$ with the estimated coefficient $\hat\beta$.

Then you run a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to see whether the distribution of the fitted values is different from the distribution of the true $X^\prime\beta$.

Why the KS test often rejects the null hypothesis?

Example in R:

```
BETA <- c(0.4, 0.4, -0.2)
x <- matrix(runif(100*3), 100, 3) # Simulate some data
y <- ifelse(x %*% BETA +  rnorm(nrow(x), sd=0.5) >0 , 1, 0)
fit <- glm(y ~ .,data=data.frame(y, x), family=binomial(link=probit))
ks.test(cbind(1, x) %*% coef(fit), x%*% BETA)$p.val
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me simplify a bit. You can think of $E[Y \vert X]$ as a conditional mean. If you had no regressors other than a constant, that would just be the regular arithmetic mean, $\bar Y$. Would you expect the distribution of the $\bar Y$ to look like the distribution of $Y$?

Comment: That is, I have $E[Y] = \mu$ then I observe a random sample $(y_i, i=1, ..., n)$ and compute the sampling mean $ \hat \mu$; the distribution of the sample mean must be centered on $\mu$ but how is the rest of the distribution

Comment: @mrb That is true, but not the point I had in mind. I am thinking of a Central Limit Theorem type of argument, where you take samples from some distribution with finite mean and variance, calculate the mean from each sample, and then plot the distribution of the means. That distribution will be normal, even if the distribution that you sample from is not. Regression is essentially a conditional mean, but the same intuition applies.

Comment: Probably you should expand this point in your final answer (as opposed to making it as another question).